# Add annotation to resizable image within scrollview

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer, zooming

I have a Scroll View in which I load an Image that can be zoomed and where I can "navigate".
I'm trying to add buttons programmatically to the view such as MKAnnotation that are used in MapKit.
Is that possible?

The methods I use are `scrollViewDidZoom`

```
  func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    centerScrollViewContents()
  }
```

where the function `centerScrollViewContents` is

```
func centerScrollViewContents() {
    let boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var contentFrame = imageView.frame
    if contentFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width {
      contentFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentFrame.size.width) / 2
    } else { contentFrame.origin.x = 0 }
    if contentFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height {
      contentFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentFrame.size.height) / 2
    } else { contentFrame.origin.y = 0 }

    imageView.frame = contentFrame
  }
```

I add the button/annotation with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` implemented as

```
let posTocco = sender.locationInView(scrollView)
println("\(posTocco), \(scrollView.zoomScale)")

var button = UIButton()
let image = UIImage(named: "arrow.png") as UIImage?
button.frame = CGRectMake(posTocco.x, posTocco.y, 30, 30)
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
scrollView.addSubview(button)
```

For sure I need to define the button/annotation outside the tapGesture function but I cannot figure out how to move the button within the image zoom.

Any help?

**EDIT:**

I partially figured out how to solve this, but the button slightly move at the first zoom in/out.
I create a new variable which stores the latest zoomValue `fattoreScalaCorrente` and in the `scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView:)` I do the magic

```
var newLoc = CGPoint(x: posAssolute.x * scrollView.zoomScale, y: posAssolute.y * scrollView.zoomScale)
button.frame = CGRectMake(newLoc.x, newLoc.y, button.frame.width, button.frame.height)
```

Do you have any idea why my button is moving slightly at the first zoom?

[image: Before zoom in/out]

[image: After zoom in/out]

**EDIT2:**
After the suggestion given using

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(newLoc.x - button.frame.width/2, newLoc.y - button.frame.height/2, button.frame.width, button.frame.height)
```

The button seems to move a little and I cannot understand why.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Read your question couple of times. What is the main question? What exact behaviour you expect? You need static button or what?

Comment: Look at the last two pictures. The first one is generate just tapping on a point and a button is added. The second one is the same situation after a zoom in and a zoom out. There is this strange situation that moves the button while I zoom the image

Comment: Hm, how do you get CGPoint  `posAssolute`?

Comment: like this: posAssolute = sender.locationInView(imageView), where imageView is the container of my Image

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: @AlexeyBondarchuk please see second edit.

Comment: Can you try to use `sender.view.frame.origin` instead of `sender.locationInView(imageViee)`? And before use check in console difference.

Comment: @AlexeyBondarchuk your suggestion give the following values for any TapGesture (-5.48363e-06, -4.36604e-06). This is really strange I imaged it would be (0,0).

Comment: Ok, what about button frame? You are using the same height and width?

Comment: @AlexeyBondarchuk of course I set width and height at the beginning as 30 by 30

Comment: I have the fillings that this is incorrect. Check that on image `x` have some insets at top and bottom. But `x` looks correct. You also can try to use `button.frame = CGRectMake(newLoc.x - button.frame.height/2, newLoc.y - button.frame.width/2, button.frame.width, button.frame.height)`. And if this will fix the problem - check frames of the button.

Comment: @AlexeyBondarchuk sorry but I don't know what do you mean by insets? I tried also the new solution but don't work either

Comment: If you'll take a look to the button you can detect that white `x` have some free space at the bottom and in the top. Can you check this in more detail?

Comment: Have you found the source of problem?

Comment: @AlexeyBondarchuk nope, at the moment I'm leaving everything as is it. Perhaps I can try using UIView with a UIImage in it instead of a button and then adding tap action properties to the view

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(newLoc.x, newLoc.y, button.frame.width, button.frame.height)
```

with

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(newLoc.x - button.frame.width/2, newLoc.y - button.frame.height/2, button.frame.width, button.frame.height)
```